# Get Value selected dropdownlist option

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have Drop Down List control and add dynamic add  option into Dropdownlist but But when I get value option return string empty

please help me
thanks

Comment: What's the code which is failing? We need more info

Comment: You wanna get the value in a jQuery function or in your code behind?

Comment: You're adding the item with jQuery, and trying to get the value in C#?

Comment: yes , curt, i adding with jquery and trying get value with c#

Comment: yes , curt, i adding with jquery and trying get value with c#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following code: `Request.Form[ddl.UniqueID]`

The code above allows to get value of selected option.

Comment: no, i add option to dropdown list with jquery and want get value selected option with c#. thanks

Comment: I'm understand this since you add `jquery` tag to your question :). This approach suitable exactly in that case.

Answer (score 1):

For Code behind

```
ddl.Items[ddl.SelectedIndex].Value
```

Comment: Have you provided the values while filling the DDL ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are populating the DropDownList. If you are using a DataSet, you should be doing something similar to this:

```
DataSet ds = yourProcedureToGetDataSet();
yourDropDownList.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["name"].Caption;
yourDropDownList.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"].Caption;
yourDropDownList.DataSource = ds;
yourDropDownList.DataBind();
yourDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a whatever", "-1"));
```

Then you can read the selected value:

```
int i = int.Parse(yourDropDownList.SelectedValue);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i add dynamic option with jquery.and get value with c#.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little method I built that worked on the site I was accessing... hopefully it will help someone :)

```
    private string GetDDLValueByName(HtmlDocument doc, string Name)
    {
        string Value = "";
        HtmlElementCollection selects = GetElementCollectionFromDocument(webBrowser1.Document, "SELECT");
        if (selects != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement select in selects)
            {
                if (select.Name == Name)
                {
                    HtmlElementCollection children = select.Children;
                    if (children.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (HtmlElement child in children)
                        {
                            if (child.OuterHtml.Contains("selected"))
                                return child.InnerText;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        return "";
                }
            }
        }
        return Value;
    }
```